# ACF post selected labels list in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an archive page that shows certain posts and want to echo a list of selected ACF labels (not values) for each specific post.

I`ve got this in the loop:

```
<?php $field = get_field_object('custom_field_name'); if( $field['choices'] ): ?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ): ?>
        <li><?php echo $label; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This however shows all the possible labels to select (not really the ones that are selected for the specific post).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $field = get_field_object('custom_field_name');

$value = $field['value'];

if( $value ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $value as $label ): ?>
        <li><?php echo $field['choices'][ $label ]; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ACF post selected labels list in WP_Query**
Add below code in your post wp query loop

```
 <?php
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $field = get_field_object('custom_field_name',$post_id );
        if( $field['choices'] ): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $label; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I guess there`s no need to implement the ID, the above solution also works (at least for me) But thanks! :)